# Sorting a list of arrays by its last character in php

Tags: php

In PHP, how might one sort an array by the last characters of its values? Take, for example, the following array:

```
$string[0] = "They";
$string[1] = "started";
$string[2] = "plotting";
$string[3] = "against";
$string[4] = "him";
```

After the sort, the array would look like this (note the order based on the last characters of each value... also note the rewritten indexes):

```
$string[0] = "started";
$string[1] = "plotting";
$string[2] = "him";
$string[3] = "against";
$string[4] = "they";
```

Comment: What are the rules to address ties?

Comment: Use `usort` and then apply whatever logic you want

Comment: And where is your own effort to solve this? The topic of [sorting arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php) has been extensively covered. You should have enough information to at least get started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows a custom sort function to be passed, so you can do:

```
usort($string , function($a, $b) {
  $aLastChar = substr($a, -1);
  $bLastChar = substr($b, -1);

  return ($aLastChar < $bLastChar) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: could u please explain me this usort function..?

Comment: @ShaluAwzme The php docs I linked to will do a much better job of that than I.

Answer (score 2):

You can invert the array value text and use sort as usual, then invert the output again.

Because you are considering the last letter of the words

```
$strings = [
 "They",
 "started",
 "plotting",
 "against",
 "him",
];
foreach ($strings as $key => $value) {
    $strings[$key] = strrev($value);
}
sort($strings);
foreach ($strings as $key => $value) {
    $strings[$key] = strrev($value);
}
print_r($strings);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => started
    [1] => plotting
    [2] => him
    [3] => against
    [4] => They
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't touched php in a long time, this is not the cleanest solution. But a quick solution is using array_map to reverse all of the strings, followed by calling sort to sort the array, then reversing the array again. A more effective solution would be by writing a custom comparer so you only iterate through the array once; rather than three times.

```
$string[0] = "They";
$string[1] = "started";
$string[2] = "plotting";
$string[3] = "against";
$string[4] = "him";

$output = array_map('strrev', $string);
sort($output);
$sorted = array_map('strrev', $output);
var_dump($sorted);
```

Edit: (Cannot comment yet):

Although thelastshadow's solution has less iterations; keep in mind that it'll only compares the last character. So once you have multiples of the same characters the storting becomes incorrect.